# Nuxt $route does not exist on Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Heyho,

I got a weird issue. I have a Nuxt app with Typescript. In the `created` hook I `console.log` `this.$route`. This log does work. As well as reading out the params from the route.

BUT I get an error in the console on building the app which is:

> Property `$route` does not exist on type `SomeClass`.

Here is my class:

```js
import Vue from'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class SomeClass extends Vue {
  public id!: string

  created() {
    console.log('this:', this)
    this.id = this.$route.params.id
  }
}
```

The `console.log` works fine and shows the correct route with it's params. 
How can I get rid of this error?

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "esnext.asynciterable",
      "dom"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/vue-app",
      "element-ui/types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It is likely to be a typescript configuration issue or missing/invalid definitions. Please, add your `tsconfig.json` or provide a reproduction repo if possible.

Comment: Hi @aBiscuit I did add my tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it thanks to @aBiscuit. It was a missing type definition in the tsconfig.
Under "types" just add @nuxt/types.

This is my new and working tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "esnext.asynciterable",
      "dom"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/vue-app",
      "element-ui/types"
    ]
  }
}
```